# How to share data between processes in Python using MPI?

Tags: python, mpi

I'm attempting to parallelize a script I wrote.  Each process needs to do a calculation and store the data to a specific part of an array (list of lists).  Each process is calculating and storing its data alright, but I can't figure out how to get the data from the non-root processes to the root process so that it can print the data out to file.  I created a minimum working example of my script---this one is designed to run on 2 cores only for simplicity:

```
from mpi4py import MPI 
import pdb 
import os

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

# Declare the array that will store all the temp results
temps = [[0 for x in xrange(5)] for x in xrange(4)]

# Loop over all directories
if rank==0:
   counter = 0 
   for i in range(2):
      for j in range(5):
         temps[i][j] = counter
     counter = counter + 1 

else:
   counter = 20
   for i in range(2,4):
      for j in range(5):
         temps[i][j] = counter
         counter = counter + 1 

temps = comm.bcast(temps,root=0)

if rank==0:

   print temps
```

I execute the script using:

```
mpiexec -n 2 python mne.py
```

When the case finishes, the output is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So you can see that the data sharing is not working as I want.  Can someone please show me the correct way to get data back to the root process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is working correctly, just not doing what you'd like.

This line

```
temps = comm.bcast(temps,root=0)
```

broadcasts processor 0's `temps` variable to all processors (including rank 0), which of course gives exactly the results above.  You want to use `gather` (or `allgather`, if you want all of the processors to have the answer).   That would look something more like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import pdb
import os

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

assert size == 2

# Declare the array that will store all the temp results
temps = [[0 for x in xrange(5)] for x in xrange(4)]

# declare the array that holds the local results
locals =[[0 for x in xrange(5)] for x in xrange(2)]

# Loop over all directories
if rank==0:
   counter = 0
   for i in range(2):
      for j in range(5):
         locals[i][j] = counter
         counter = counter + 1

else:
   counter = 20
   for i in range(2):
      for j in range(5):
         locals[i][j] = counter
         counter = counter + 1

temps = comm.gather(locals,temps,root=0)

if rank==0:
   print temps
```

If you really want to do the collection in-place, and you know (say) that all the real data is going to be larger than the zero you've initialized the data with, you can use a reduction operation, but that goes easier with numpy arrays:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

assert size == 2

# Declare the array that will store all the temp results
temps = numpy.zeros((4,5))

# Loop over all directories
if rank==0:
   counter = 0
   for i in range(2):
      for j in range(5):
         temps[i,j] = counter
         counter = counter + 1

else:
   counter = 20
   for i in range(2,4):
      for j in range(5):
         temps[i,j] = counter
         counter = counter + 1

comm.Allreduce(MPI.IN_PLACE,temps,op=MPI.MAX)

if rank==0:
   print temps
```

Comment: I got the following error while compiling the 1st code:
`TypeError: gather() got multiple values for keyword argument 'root'TypeError: gather() got multiple values for keyword argument 'root'`